# Perl regex to match but only replace in blocks

Tags: regex, perl

This is such a stupid question to ask - but I'm drawing a blank! I have a test string:

```
Foo|||bar||something|whatever
```

I need to replace `||` with `|EMPTY_STRING|` for each instance.

I'm doing:

```
s/\Q||/|EMPTY_STRING|/g;
```

The problem is, that this converts it to:

```
Foo|EMPTY_STRING||bar|EMPTY_STRING|something|whatever
```

Notice the || in there. I must be missing something stupid. What is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use lookaround in your regex:

```
s='Foo|||bar||something|whatever'

perl -pe 's/(?<=\|)(?=\|)/EMPTY_STRING/g' <<< "$s"
```

```
Foo|EMPTY_STRING|EMPTY_STRING|bar|EMPTY_STRING|something|whatever
```

**RegEx Detail:**

- `(?<=\|)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `|` behind current position
- `(?=\|)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `|` ahead of current position

Comment: Actually you don't need both Lookahead and Lookbehinds. One of them is enough. `s/\|(?=\|)/|EMPTY_STRING/g` and `s/(?<=\|)\|/EMPTY_STRING|/g` work both.